# Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9 because no repositories are defined

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jdk-desugaring

I am using Android Studio version 4.1.2. My project was working fine. I updated it to Android Studio 4.1.3. I still get the errors on reinstalling AS 4.1.2. I started getting the following error:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:coreLibraryDesugaring'.
Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :app
```

On running the following command in terminal:

```
$ ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see TBD.
To determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.databinding:viewbinding:4.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :axnetwork-library
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:4.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :axnetwork-library
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:4.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :axnetwork-library
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.xwray:groupie:2.8.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.xwray:groupie-databinding:2.8.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.annimon:stream:1.2.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.nulab-inc:zxcvbn:1.3.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency net.openid:appauth:0.7.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:69)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:161)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:165)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:144)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:45)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:126)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:117)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.run(BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareTaskExecution(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:120)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1761)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.iterator(DefaultConfiguration.java:1733)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:300)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:224)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitDependencies(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:112)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:67)
        ... 106 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.databinding:viewbinding:4.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :app


*
```

The build.gradle files:
axnetwork-library
annexandroid
app

**annexandroid (build.gradle)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'

        ***

        }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**axnetwork-lib build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ***
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'

    implementation project(path: ':draggablechip-library')
//    implementation 'annexandroid:draggablechip-library:1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    ***
}
```

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    signingConfigs {
           ***
        }

        debug {
           ***
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.annex.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 51
        versionName "0.44"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        ***
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ***
        }

        release {
         ***
        }


    }
    compileOptions {
/*        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'*/
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                srcDirs 'src/main/res', 'src/main/res/dashboard'
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
//    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson-extras:2.8.6'
//    implementation 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:4.8'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'
//    implementation 'xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3'
    /*implementation 'com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-viewbinding:2.8.1'*/


    implementation "com.xwray:groupie:2.8.1"
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-databinding:2.8.1'

//    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-viewbinding:2.8.1'
//    implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-databinding:2.8.0"
//    implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-viewbinding:2.8.0"

    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':axnetwork-library')

    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

         ***

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
//    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    ***

    //Desugaring - Used for Streams
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
//    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs_configuration:1.0.9'
//    implementation 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'

    //test libraries
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'

    //AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.1.0'

    // The following Espresso dependency can be either "implementation"
    // or "androidTestImplementation", depending on whether you want the
    // dependency to appear on your APK's compile classpath or the test APK
    // classpath.
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.0'
/*
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
*/
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'

    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1"

    implementation project(":draggablechip-library")

}
```

Comment: Post also the settings.gradle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to add in your `build.gradle` the `repositories` block

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

or in your `settings.gradle`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally I got solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add these lines in gradle.properties

```html
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```